# Debugging node.js in Visual Studio Code preview on OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying out the newly released Visual Studio Code preview on Mac OS X, when trying to start debugging or attaching to my node.js app I get the error "Cannot start OpenDebug because Mono (or a Mono version >= 3.10.0) is required".

I have installed the Mono MDK from http://www.mono-project.com/download/.

What do I need to do to get debugging working in VSCode preview?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did a `brew install mono` and the problem went away the next time I hit the run button.

Unfortunately, I have no idea why the MDK installer wouldn't work for you. This was an optimal solution for me since I use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for most other development tools already.

Comment: Thanks! I Tried getting mono from Macports but it was a lower version than the required one.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your mono installation did not add mono to the PATH, thus visual studio code: preview could not find it. `brew install mono` should fix the issue

Comment: What should the PATH read? I have tried to do the brew install mono but got `Error: SHA1 mismatch` every time I tried to install it.
So as I have installed the mono 4.0.0 as written above, I just want to correct the OSX PATH, to...?

Comment: A colleague of mine got the SHA1 mismatch and needed to do a ```brew upgrade``` before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I Installed mono on my ubuntu and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```